# Element with `contenteditable` exhibiting strange cursor postion

Tags: css, html

I'm using `contenteditable` on a `h1` element with a generous `line-height`. When I try editing the `h1`, I have to position my cursor at the very top of the element boundary. I want to be able to directly click on the element and edit it's text.

HTML:

```
   <div>
     <h1 contenteditable="true">Edit Me</h1>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
  h1 { 
      font: 16px/48px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
     }
```

I've tried reducing the `line-height` , but the problem still persists. The following image is a representation of the problem.

[image: The following image is a representation of the problem.]

Comment: here's a [demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/Sv9H4/) but can't recreate the issue.  maybe overlap from another element is in the way?

Comment: I don't think so—  I thought it might be the `:hover` state on the container div, which I removed, but there was no positive affect.

Comment: Without a JSFiddle that replicates the issue it's all speculation!

Comment: I've tried to replicate the issue on jsFiddle without success. Speculation is better than nothing, and, there's always the chance that another person may have had a similar issue.